# BigQuery - how many entries per partition?

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I have big partitioned tables and try to figure out **how many entries** are in each **day-partition**. 
So far I used a `for loop` in a script but there must be a simpler way doing it.

Google did not help me. Does anyone know the right query?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can run the following query to count how many entries you have in each partition

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  _PARTITIONTIME AS pt,
  COUNT(1)
FROM
  `dataset.table` 
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  1 DESC
```

and

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  _PARTITIONTIME AS pt,
  COUNT(1)
FROM
  [dataset:table]
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  1 DESC
```

it returns a table like this, please note that the `NULL` entries are still in streaming buffer. Hint: to obtain records which are in streaming buffer us a query with NULL.

```
+-------------------------+-----+--+
| 2017-02-14 00:00:00 UTC | 252 |  |
+-------------------------+-----+--+
| 2017-02-13 00:00:00 UTC | 257 |  |
+-------------------------+-----+--+
| 2017-02-12 00:00:00 UTC | 188 |  |
+-------------------------+-----+--+
| 2017-02-11 00:00:00 UTC | 234 |  |
+-------------------------+-----+--+
| 2017-02-10 00:00:00 UTC | 107 |  |
+-------------------------+-----+--+
| null                    | 13  |  |
+-------------------------+-----+--+
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you used legacy SQL?

Comment: added standard as well

Comment: Brilliant @Pentium10!

Comment: This used to work earlier, but now I am getting an error "Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONTIME ". Anyone facing same issue?

Comment: I am also now getting 'Unrecognized name' errors when using the _PARTITIONTIME pseudo - column; any Googlers here know why that might be?

Comment: _PARTITIONTIME and _PARTITIONDATE are pseudo columns present only in tables paritioned by ingestion time.